# compilation error, package javax.ws.rs does not exist, dependencies not resolved from maven

Tags: maven

I had mentioned the dependency libraries in the pom file, also the library system path exists also, but during the compilation using maven clean install  -e -X, it throws error saying  the package does not exists.

```
**[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[4,19] C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:4: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[5,19] C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:5: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[6,19] C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:6: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[8,1] C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:8: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/gopc/workspace/RestfulService/src/restfu/Hello.java:[21,2] C:\Users\gopc\workspace\RestfulService\src\restfu\Hello.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Path**
```

### **POM file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestfulService</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestfulService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/build/classes</outputDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

</build>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>jersey-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/javax.ws.rs.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to include the Java EE dependencies in your POM, with a `provided` scope (aka, the files will *eventually* be provided by the application server, but in the meantime I need them for compilation).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i had added the dependency, but still the error remains the same.

Comment: Edit your question please, to include relevant portions of your class.

Comment: i had added the folder called library in my project (RestfulService) and added the jar file javax.ws.rs.jar also i had included the dependency in the pom file with the system path, but still it say's the package does not exist why...

Comment: i resolved the issue , i add the dependencies in the <project> instead of dependency management

Comment: i am not working in maven then where should i place the javaee jar file or where and how to include the dependencies

Answer (score 9):

I had this and more similar issues after system update, when NetBeans changed fonts, and GUI in general. I have resolved this issue by adding `Java EE 6 API Library` in NetBeans IDE by doing

`myProject->Properties->Libraries->Add Library`

Comment: This actually helped me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

The dependency that @Perception replied with is also needed but it was not enough for me as well. The following dependency was also needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0

Τhis fixed the problem for me!

Comment: Looks like it needs both dependencies: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>                         SOURCE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355477/maven-in-eclipse-project-package-javax-ws-rs-does-not-exist

Answer (score 4):

I think this dependency is better

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The modern day answer will be as below :

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
          </dependency>
        
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Note to anyone who sees `jakarta...3.X`, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Jersey is published in java.net repository; just use this (or better edit your user settings.xml):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[JSR311](http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/) (javax.ws.rs) will be downloaded automatically by maven as a jersey-core dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by adding the dependencies in between the `<project>` tags instead of in dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was IntelliJ 'make' that was not working, although mvn clean install worked fine. The way to resolve it is to remove the two erroneous "Modules" from the "project Structure"->Modules tab, the modules were: main and test. Somehow they got in there from 'create project from existing source'.

Answer (score 0):

I came through this error, the solution for me was to have both of this dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue the same approach as @BugsForBreakfast.
But wanted to share that javax.ws.rs-api artifact is been moved now.
One can use the dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```