# Maven in Eclipse project: package javax.ws.rs does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven, tomcat

In Eclipse, when I go to myProject -> right click -> Run As -> Maven build, I am getting multiple errors in the console outlining that certain packages does not exist, like:

```
javax.ws.rs does not exist
javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
javax.servlet does not exist
javax.servlet.http doest not exist
```

Although in my pom.xml, I have provided those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
etc
```

under

```
<dependencyManagement><dependecies>
```

tags (don't have any errors in pom.xml).

I do also have proxy settings configured in settings.xml file, and this file is properly linked.

I've also got these jars included locally to WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder and added to the classpath (I can run my REST service on tomcat, the error "package does not exist" appears only when I am trying to use Maven build".

The reason I need that I want to generate and deploy a .war file.

How I can solve this? Is there a war to force Maven look in local libraries instead?

Comment: To check where comes from your problem, first : run  mvn clean install in command line at the root of your mvn project and give us a feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

then you need to have a separate:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

section.

Typically you would define `dependencyManagement` in a parent pom.xml file and then use the second `dependencies` fragment in child pom.xml files. This ensures that all your modules depend upon the same consistent artifacts.