# IntelliJ import ADOxx dependencies automatically?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ and I decided to start my project on this IDEA since I have heard/seen many good reviews on it.

So, I need to import some ADOxx dependencies and I followed the following steps described for the Eclipse IDEA. https://www.adoxx.org/live/adoxx-web-api-extend

I have successfully added Maven dependencies (manually adding the missing ones to the .pom file, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881110/4141871) but there are still many errors with adoxx missing packages. Is there any way to automatically import the dependencies or do I need to find the correct dependencies and import each one of the manually?

Some of the errors shown are:

```
Error:(4, 50) java: package org.adoxx.basis.dao.client.adoxx.AdoScript does not exist
Error:(3, 40) java: package org.adoxx.basis.dao.client.adoxx does not exist
Error:(5, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(6, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(7, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(12, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(13, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(14, 43) java: package org.adoxx.basis.read.model.response does not exist
Error:(16, 30) java: package io.swagger.annotations does not exist
Error:(17, 30) java: package io.swagger.annotations does not exist
```

Comment: Please check that all needed dependencies are mentioned in "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies". IDEA automatically detects dependencies from pom files. Othre dependencies should be configured manually or via parent pom file

Comment: @y.bedrov Yes it was indeed an error with missing dependencies. Since there were 3 projects with inderdependencies, I had to add the Modules manually. Thanks!